# Can I call MAPI32.DLL > MAPISendMail from a 64-bit C# Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, 64-bit, mapi

I have converted a 32-bit WinForms application to 64-bit, but am unsure about what to with a call to MAPI32.DLL > MAPISendMail?  I didn't think you could call a 32-bit dll directly from a 64-bit one, but thought I would see what happens.  Curiously, it seems to work, but I don't know if it is safe.

The DLL is called as follows:

```
[DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
public static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr session, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);

//...fill in message

// Call the API
int error = Mapi32.MAPISendMail(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, message, Mapi32.MAPI_DIALOG, 0);
```

Is it safe to do this from a 64-bit WinForms app, or am I just lucky it doesn't crash?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/building-mapi-applications-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. An appropriate library will be used and loaded (mapi32.dll) from the appropriate system directory:

- x64 or x86 natively

```
%windir%\system32\mapi32.dll
```

- x86 on WoW mode

```
%windir%\syswow64\mapi32.dll
```

You can read more about that in the [Building MAPI applications on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/building-mapi-applications-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-platforms) article.

Comment: Thanks.  I have now confirmed using "Process Explorer" that my 32-bit app loads "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mapi32.dll" while my 64-bit app loads "C:\Windows\System32".  So Windows automatically finds the correct dll to use depending on the bit-ness of my app.